# What exactly is causing these 'undefined methods' errors?

Tags: java

I have a `PhoneBook` class that extends `AbstractCollection<Contact>` in which I have overwritten `add`, `size` and `iterator` methods. In the main function I create a new instance of the `PhoneBook` class and attempt to add a `Contact` to it using the `add` method.

Apparently everything compiles fine however I get an exception at runtime saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method add(Contact) is undefined for the type PhoneBook
    The method add(Contact) is undefined for the type PhoneBook
    The method size() is undefined for the type PhoneBook
```

I don't know why this is happening and my searches didn't bring up any useful information. The code that's causing the error:

```
public class PhoneBook extends AbstractCollection<Contact> {
    private HashSet<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public boolean add(Contact newContact) {
        return contacts.add(newContact);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return contacts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Contact> iterator() {
        return contacts.iterator();
    }
}

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PhoneBook book = new PhoneBook();

        book.add(new Contact("Marco Polo", "asd@acf.com"));
        book.add(new Contact("Pablo Cablo", "asd@ccf.com"));
        book.size();

        System.out.println(book);
    }

}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is an closing parenthesis missing in `book.add(...)`. Other than that, your code compiles fine.

Comment: How are you running your code? Are you sure this isn't some classpath issue? the code works fine for me. Is there any other `PhoneBook` class in the classpath?

Comment: Also, you should avoid trying to run code that doesn't compile. Fix the compiler errors first.

Comment: @JBNizet: fixed it, it was a mistake done while writing the question.

Comment: Are you sure that you are compiling all files? Make sure that you arn't accidently compiling an old copy of one of the java files or something like that. Delete all of your .class files and recompile and check that they are there.

Comment: Also make sure you don't have multiple PhoneBook or Contact classes, and that you're not importing another PhoneBook or Contact class from another package.

Comment: @NickWeedon That did it, apparently some java files that had modifications did not get automatically recompiled when building the project.

Comment: Yeah it's a good thing to do when 'weird shit' starts happening. It happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you are compiling all files? Make sure that you arn't accidently compiling an old copy of one of the java files or something like that. Delete all of your .class files and recompile and check that they are there.

Comment: If you could up my answer that would be great :]

Comment: Oh crap, sorry about that. Was a cut & past error, meant to grab my own comment :/

Comment: Fixed.. it now reads my own comment. Thanks for letting me know :)